# Increase performance - getting rid of .SD?

Tags: r, data.table

table Gurus! This is a follow up question to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238031/subsetting-within-a-subset/19238524?noredirect=1#comment28508868_19238524) which I posted here a few days ago. I am addressing myself to you with a question how to improve the performance of the following application of `data.table`:

The function (for the purpose envisaged that's the fastest possible):

```
prob <- function(a, ie1, b, a1, ie2, b2, ...) {
ipf  <- function(a, b, ...) {
m    <- length(a)
n    <- length(b)
if (m < n) {
    r <- rank(c(a, b), ...)[1:m] - 1:m
} else {
    r <- rank(c(a, b), ...)[(m + 1):(m + n)] - 1:n
}
s <- ifelse((n + m)^2 > 2^31, sum(as.double(r)), sum(r))/(as.double(m) * n)
return(ifelse(m < n, s, 1 - s))
}

expand.grid.alt <- function(seq1, seq2) {
cbind(rep.int(seq1, length(seq2)), c(t(matrix(rep.int(seq2, length(seq1)), nrow =   length(seq2)))))
}

if (missing(a1) | missing(b2) | missing(ie2)) {
if (ie1 == ">") {
    return(ipf(a, b))
} else {
    return(ipf(b, a))
}
} else {
if (ie1 == ">") {
    if (ie2 == ">") {
        return(ipf(a, apply(expand.grid.alt(b, b2), 1, max))/ipf(a1, b2))
    } else {
        return(1 - ipf(apply(expand.grid.alt(b, b2), 1, min), a)/(1 - ipf(a1, b2)))
    }
 } else {
    if (ie2 == ">") {
        return(1 - ipf(a, apply(expand.grid.alt(b, b2), 1, max))/ipf(a1, b2))
    } else {
        return(ipf(apply(expand.grid.alt(b, b2), 1, min), a)/(1 - ipf(a1, b2)))
    }
}
}
}
```

Some notes to the function: This functions allows to compare different samples via a rank-sum procedure. It allows to efficiently compute e.g. the probability that a draw from sample A exceeds a draw from sample B given that the draw from sample A exceeds a draw from sample C. In the case here I just want to compute the probability that a draw from A[.I] exceeds a draw from B given that a draw from A[.I] exceeds a draw from A[-.I]. Where .I stands for all ids. And additionally to that I would like to do that for all dates. This is where the not good .SD comes into play. Please note that for the above described task prob() is already pretty much the fastest one can find.

The data set:

```
dt <- data.table(id=rep(c(rep(1,50),rep(2,50),rep(3,100),rep(4,50),rep(5,100),rep(6,50),rep(7,50),rep(8,50),rep(9,50),rep(10,50)),5),date=c(rep("2004-01-01",600),rep("2004-02-01",600),rep("2004-03-01",600),rep("2004-04-01",600),rep("2004-05-01",600)),A=runif(3000,-5,5),B=runif(3000,-5,5))
```

The application of data.table:

```
setkey(dt, id)
setkey(dt, id)
dt[,{
.SD1 <- .SD;
.SD1[,prob(.SD1$A[.I],">",.SD1$B,.SD1$A[.I],">",.SD1$A[-.I]), by=id ]
},by=date]
```

On my machine the execution of this task takes around 52.1 sec. This is way too much considering that my real data set has severall million rows and all in all 57 groups (ids). Do you have any suggestions for me to increase performance here? **I am actually looking for a data.table solution. I believe that the data table syntax might be inefficient. Maybe one could get rid of .SD?** But I am also open to parallelization ideas.

### ----------

**Update**

Below is the status quo. I parallelized the procedure which brings an improvement of the performance. Every hint how to make the procedure even more efficient is highly appreciated, because I think I am missing something in the parallelization - I expected a more significant increase of performance.

**Packages**

```
library(multicore)
library(doMC)
library(data.table)
registerDoMC(cores=4)
```

**data set**

```
dt <-     data.table(id=rep(c(rep(1,50),rep(2,50),rep(3,100),rep(4,50),rep(5,100),rep(6,50),rep(7,50),rep(8,50),rep(9,50),rep(10,50)),5),date=c(rep("2004-01-01",600),rep("2004-02-01",600),rep("2004-03-01",600),rep("2004-04-01",600),rep("2004-05-01",600)),A=runif(3000,-5,5),B=runif(3000,-5,5))
```

**prob() function OP**

```
prob1 <- function(a, ie1, b, a1, ie2, b2, ...) {
ipf  <- function(a, b, ...) {
m    <- length(a)
n    <- length(b)
sm <- seq_len(m)
sn <- seq_len(n)
if (m < n) {
  r <- rank(c(a, b), ...)[sm] - sm
} else {
  r <- rank(c(a, b), ...)[(m + sn)] - sn
}
s <- ifelse((n + m)^2 > 2^31, sum(as.double(r)), sum(r))/(as.double(m) * n)
return(ifelse(m < n, s, 1 - s))
}


if (missing(a1) | missing(b2) | missing(ie2)) {
if (ie1 == ">") {
  return(ipf(a, b))
} else {
  return(ipf(b, a))
}
} else {
if (ie1 == ">") {
  if (ie2 == ">") {
    return(ipf(a,CJ(b, b2)[,pmax(V1,V2)])/ipf(a1, b2))
  } else {
    return(1 - ipf(CJ(b, b2)[,pmin(V1,V2)], a)/(1 - ipf(a1, b2)))
  }
} else {
  if (ie2 == ">") {
    return(1 - ipf(a,CJ(b, b2)[,pmax(V1,V2)])/ipf(a1, b2))
  } else {
    return(ipf(CJ(b, b2)[,pmin(V1,V2)], a)/(1 - ipf(a1, b2)))
  }
}
}
}
```

**prob() function mnel**

```
prob2 <- function(a, ie1, b, a1, ie2, b2, ...) { 
ipf  <- function(a, b, ...) {
m    <- length(a)
n    <- length(b)
sm <- seq_len(m)
sn <- seq_len(n)
if (m < n) {
  r <- rank(c(a, b), ...)[sm] - sm
} else {
  r <- rank(c(a, b), ...)[(m + sn)] - sn
}
s <- if((n + m)^2 > 2^31){sum(as.double(r))/(as.double(m) * n)} else{     sum(r)/(as.double(m) * n)}
return(if(m < n){s} else{1 - s})
}

if (missing(a1) | missing(b2) | missing(ie2)) {
if (ie1 == ">") {
  return(ipf(a, b))
} else {
  return(ipf(b, a))
}
} else {
if (ie1 == ">") {
  if (ie2 == ">") {

    ipfb <- pmax(rep.int(b,length(b2)), rep(b2, each = length(b)))
    return(ipf(a, ipfb) /ipf(a1, b2))
  } else {
    ipfb <- pmin(rep.int(b,length(b2)), rep(b2, each = length(b)))
    return(1 - ipf(ipfb, a)/(1 - ipf(a1, b2)))
  }
} else {
  if (ie2 == ">") {
    ipfb <- pmax(rep.int(b,length(b2)), rep(b2, each = length(b)))
    return(1 - ipf(a, ipfb )/ipf(a1, b2))
  } else {
    ipfb <- pmin(rep.int(b,length(b2)), rep(b2, each = length(b)))
    return(ipf(ipfb, a)/(1 - ipf(a1, b2)))
  }
}
}
}
```

**prob function OP - applied to data.table**

```
ptm <- proc.time()
setkey(dt, id)
res1 <- dt[,{
.SD1 <- .SD;
.SD1[,prob1(.SD1$A[.I],">",.SD1$B,.SD1$A[.I],">",.SD1$A[-.I]),by=id]},by=date]
proc.time() - ptm

user  system elapsed 
6.645   0.110   6.778
```

**prob function mnel - applied to data.table**

```
ptm <- proc.time()
setkey(dt, id)
res2 <- dt[,{
.SD1 <- .SD;
.SD1[,prob2(.SD1$A[.I],">",.SD1$B,.SD1$A[.I],">",.SD1$A[-.I]),by=id]},by=date]
proc.time() - ptm

user  system elapsed 
5.914   0.065   5.999
```

**parallelized prob function - OP - applied to data.table**

```
ptm <- proc.time()
jo        <- dt[,list(jobs=list(parallel({.SD1 <- .SD; .SD1[,prob1(.SD1$A[.I],">",.SD1$B,.SD1$A[.I],">",.SD1$A[-.I]),by=id]}))),by=date]
res3      <- data.table(date=rep(jo[,date],each=length(unique(dt$id))),rbindlist(collect(jo[,jobs])))
proc.time() - ptm


user  system elapsed 
13.882   0.537   4.715
```

**parallelized prob function - mnel - applied to data.table**

```
ptm <- proc.time()
jo        <- dt[,list(jobs=list(parallel({.SD1 <- .SD; .SD1[,prob2(.SD1$A[.I],">",.SD1$B,.SD1$A[.I],">",.SD1$A[-.I]),by=id]}))),by=date]
res4      <- data.table(date=rep(jo[,date],each=length(unique(dt$id))),rbindlist(collect(jo[,jobs])))
proc.time() - ptm

user  system elapsed 
13.682   0.560   4.545
```

Comment: I'm sure that a lot of thought went into constructing that function, but its purpose seems quite unclear to my reading. You should put in comments and describe the purpose and the expected output on that set of data. It's also not syntacticly complete. Pasting it into a console fails to return to a command prompt.

Comment: please explain the problem you're solving **in words**

Comment: What exactly is the point of `.SD` here? And why not use `by=list(date, id)`?

Comment: Also, using `[.I]` makes no sense. That's like `A[1:length(A)]`

Comment: @DWin Sorry, that is embarrassing. The function should now work and I also added an explanation to the function.

Comment: @eddi I added a comment to the function.

Comment: @SeñorO .SD is used because we split by=date first and then apply another operation (the prob() function) on .SD. That is exactly the point. Do your second comment: That is the only way it is yielding the correct results, I also thought this would not be necessary. The A[-.I] is something I need for my calculations.

Comment: Where is "sample C"?.

Comment: When calculating a conditional probability of event X given Y, write `DT[Y,sum(X)/.N]`, don't use a function...

Comment: @DWin this was just an example what you could do with it.

Comment: @Frank: Sorry, but I am computing conditional probabilities for draws from random samples. This unfortunately doesn't work that way (it is inaccurate). You can either look at all combinations (inefficient) or use rank-sum approaches as in the function above.

Comment: @DWin this was just an example what you could do with it. That is not relevant here. Here I just want to compute the probability that a draw from A[.I] exceeds a draw from B given that a draw from A[.I] exceeds a draw from A[-.I]. Where I stands for all ids. And additionally to that I would like to do that for all dates. This is where the not good .SD comes into play.

Comment: @chameau13 I like the challenge you've presented here and issues you've raised, but I think this will turn out better if you find what parts are hogging all the processing time and then see if we have any suggestions on improving just those parts.

Comment: @SeñorO The problem is that prob() is by far the fastest way to do what I want to do. I stated this above already. And to speed things up would like to apply it in a data table framework. In there it hinges. I believe that the data table syntax could be more efficient.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm saying.

Comment: @SeñorO Hm ... I believe that the use of .SD is a problem because all the split up data tables go into the memory. I am looking for a solution to make the data table syntax more efficient.

Comment: I would like to know what are the objections tho this question? Why the down ratings? Help me to improve the question!

Comment: @chameau13 I have an answer without an `.SD`, but it's still very slow. I think you're just doing a very computationally intensive operation. Perhaps there is a way to compute this using `rank(A)` and `rank(c(A,B))`... As it is, I suspect you are making many repeated comparisons.

Comment: It is all to do with the function `prob` being inefficient. Profile the code and see my answer for an example that gives a 10 fold speed up

Comment: @mnel thank you so much! i will do so!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `data.table` and using `.SD`
If you profile your original call (using `profr` for example) you will notice that most of the time is spent in `t.default` and the `FUN` argument to `apply`.

```
library(profr); library(ggplot2
xpr <- profr(dt[,{
  .SD1 <- .SD;
  .SD1[,prob(.SD1$A[.I],">",.SD1$B,.SD1$A[.I],">",.SD1$A[-.I]), by=id ]
  },by=date])

ggplot(xpr)
```

[image]

You could rewrite your `expand.grid.alt` function to remove the unnecessary calls to `matrix` and `t`

```
 expand.grid.alt <- function(seq1,seq2){
   cbind(rep.int(seq1,length(seq2)), rep(seq2,each=length(seq1)))
 }
```

But this won't fix the fact you are using `apply` to get vectorized maximum and minimum values accros two rows. You can use `pmin` or `pmax` to do this (and get an 8-9 fold increase for even a small example)

```
pm <- function(seq1,seq2){
 pmax(rep.int(seq1,length(seq2)), rep(seq2, each = length(seq1)))}
ea <- function(seq1, seq2) {
  apply(cbind(rep.int(seq1, length(seq2)), rep(seq2, each = length(seq1))),1,max)
  }
 eaorig <- function(seq1, seq2) {
   cbind(rep.int(seq1, length(seq2)), 
         c(t(matrix(rep.int(seq2, length(seq1)), nrow =   length(seq2)))))
    }
 eao <- function(seq1,seq2) {apply( eaorig(seq1,seq2), 1, max)}

 library(microbenchmark)

 microbenchmark(pm(1:5,2:8), ea(1:5,2:8),eao(1:5,2:8))
Unit: microseconds
          expr    min      lq  median      uq     max neval
  pm(1:5, 2:8) 10.867 11.7730 12.6790 13.2820  56.446   100
  ea(1:5, 2:8) 80.895 83.6130 85.5745 88.4420 172.054   100
 eao(1:5, 2:8) 91.460 94.0265 95.6860 99.3085 137.341   100
```

We can then redefine

```
prob <- function(a, ie1, b, a1, ie2, b2, ...) {
  ipf  <- function(a, b, ...) {
    m    <- length(a)
    n    <- length(b)
    sm <- seq_len(m)
    sn <- seq_len(n)
    if (m < n) {
      r <- rank(c(a, b), ...)[sm] - sm
    } else {
      r <- rank(c(a, b), ...)[(m + sn)] - sn
    }
    s <- if((n + m)^2 > 2^31){sum(as.double(r))/(as.double(m) * n)} else{ sum(r)/(as.double(m) * n)}
    return(if(m < n){s} else{1 - s})
  }

  if (missing(a1) | missing(b2) | missing(ie2)) {
    if (ie1 == ">") {
      return(ipf(a, b))
    } else {
      return(ipf(b, a))
    }
  } else {
    if (ie1 == ">") {
      if (ie2 == ">") {

        ipfb <- pmax(rep.int(b,length(b2)), rep(b2, each = length(b)))
        return(ipf(a, ipfb) /ipf(a1, b2))
      } else {
        ipfb <- pmin(rep.int(b,length(b2)), rep(b2, each = length(b)))
        return(1 - ipf(ipfb, a)/(1 - ipf(a1, b2)))
      }
    } else {
      if (ie2 == ">") {
        ipfb <- pmax(rep.int(b,length(b2)), rep(b2, each = length(b)))
        return(1 - ipf(a, ipfb )/ipf(a1, b2))
      } else {
        ipfb <- pmin(rep.int(b,length(b2)), rep(b2, each = length(b)))
        return(ipf(ipfb, a)/(1 - ipf(a1, b2)))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Having rewritten `prob` we get a 10 fold speed up

```
# avoiding .SD
system.time({ 
 # create lists of B by 'date
 Bs <- dt[,list(x = list(B)),keyby='date'];

 dt[,{
   z <- .BY
   BB <- Bs[z[[1]]][['x']][[1]]
   AA <- dt[!list(z[['id']]), A[date == z[['date']]]]
  prob(A, '>',BB,A,'>',AA) 
 },by='date,id']  
 })
   user  system elapsed 
   4.66    0.00    4.67 

# using original .SD approach 
system.time( dt[,{
  .SD1 <- .SD;
  .SD1[,prob(.SD1$A[.I],">",.SD1$B,.SD1$A[.I],">",.SD1$A[-.I]), by=id ]
 },by=date])
   user  system elapsed 
   4.51    0.00    4.52 

 # using probo == original function

system.time( dt[,{
 .SD1 <- .SD;
 .SD1[,probo(.SD1$A[.I],">",.SD1$B,.SD1$A[.I],">",.SD1$A[-.I]), by=id ]
},by=date])

 user  system elapsed 
  43.98    0.02   44.01
```

#### Edit with updated function from OP

Using `CJ` and pmax within a call to `[.`

```
# if we compare this with the updated version using `CJ`

system.time( dt[,{
     .SD1 <- .SD;
     .SD1[,prob1(.SD1$A[.I],">",.SD1$B,.SD1$A[.I],">",.SD1$A[-.I]), by=id ]
 },by=date])
   user  system elapsed 
  17.23    0.00   17.27
```

This is slower due to the overhead in calling `[.data.table` and the fact that `CJ` sets the key on the created `data.table`

Comment: I just did exactly the same. I already noted it in the comment above: Without having this great tool profr I already suspected that expandgrid.alt and apply are the reason and right so: I used CJ(A,B)[,pmax(V1,V2)] instead and got a 14 time speed increase. I think however I will try further to parallelize tasks there and post my results tomorrow.

Comment: Could you explain that graph?

Comment: @chameau13 -- using `CJ` and a subsequent call to `[.data.table` will have unnecessary overhead....

Comment: @mnel really? i posted the new function above. i have to go to bed now (2am). i will check back tomorrow. I am sure there is some space of improvement and i will keep you updated.

Comment: @mnel On my RHEL 6.4 i7-2640M and 8 GB RAM: The CJ() and data.table call is slightly faster than your pm() function and thus my version of the prob function is also slightly faster. I get back to you if I have more results.

Comment: @mnel so in my original post I added a parallelized version of the procedure. it brought an increase in performance, which is however not as huge as i expected it to be (hoped).